# FAX / Ubuntu interface

Tags: usb, pstn

Is there a way to have access from Ubuntu 12.04 (LibreOffice Writer OR other) to an Epson Stylus NX305 FAX?

The FAX machine has a PSTN (Public Switched Telephone Network) port and a USB (Universal Serial Bus) port and works well as a stand alone FAX (facsimile) using the PSTN port for both incoming and outgoing FAX. I would like to be able to send FAX requests directly from the computer so I do not need to take the extra steps to print and scan the outgoing FAX. It would also be nice to divert incoming FAX so they need not be scanned to save the FAX on the computer.

Print and scan work well, but it would be nice to save ink in printing the FAX. Most of the companies with which I deal have FAX which makes it a more secure option than email and a lot faster than a courier service like USPS (United States Postal Service), UPS (United Parcel Service), FedEx (Federal Express), etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, fax is far less secure than email. Never transmit any private or secure information over a fax. Anybody can walk right outside your building to the TNI box and get all of your faxes.

If you are looking for a solution for interfacing fax with your computer, you have a few options.

- You could buy a fax modem for your computer and hook up the line to it.
- You could port your fax number to an online fax service provider.
- You could port your fax number to a SIP provider and build your own fax interface using asterisk and spandsp.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.

I disagree with your assessment of security. A FAX transmitted over the PSTN (Public Switched Telephone Network) is HIPAA compliant. Emails are not HIPAA compliant. I have not checked out any internet based FAX services for HIPAA compliance, but I will before I subscribe.

Anyone can physically tap a PSTN or internet connection at any of the terminals or even by putting in a splice in the cable. I have yet to hear of anyone actually hacking the PSTN from a server or relay. I hear many horror stories about hackers taking advantage of account data sent by email.